# Python: sum the elements of a list if it is longer than 1

Tags: python

I have a simple problem:

I have a list of lists, like that:

```
 X=   [[0], [4,5,6], [1], [4], [3, 4]]
```

I want to transform it in a list of lists all of length 1, where the sublists>1 are summed, like that:

```
[[0], [15], [1], [4], [7]]
```

How can I achieve this output? This is what I tried:

```
for z in range(len(X)):
    if len(X[z])>1:
        sum(X[z])
```

but it does not work

Comment: `[[sum(x)] for x in X]`

Comment: Why would it work? You don't *do anything* with the sum.

Comment: Why bother testing for length?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a list that contain only one element, the sum of the inner list.

```
sum_list = [[sum(il)] for il in X]
```

by `[sum(il)]` you create this new list (which be a member of `sum_list`) and init it with one element.

Comment: Same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018834/python-sum-the-elements-of-a-list-if-it-is-longer-than-1#comment106145724_60018834

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get simpler than what Chris said in its comment: `[[sum(x)] for x in X]`

Your code doesn't work because you don't assign the sum result in your 'main' list. Following your example `X[z] = [sum(X[z])]` should work instead of just `sum(X[z])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're looking for a different answer (@green's answer is recommended)

```py
x = [[0], [4,5,6], [1], [4], [3, 4]]
y = []

for each_list in x:
    sum_of_elem_list = []
    sum_of_elem = 0;
    for each_elem in each_list:
        sum_of_elem+=each_elem;

    sum_of_elem_list.append(sum_of_elem)
    y.append(sum_of_elem_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using reduce function in functools,

```
from functools import reduce
print([[reduce(lambda i,j: i+j, k)] for k in X])
```